# Custom buttom with custom URL in salesforce1

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, custom-button

I had to do a custom buttom on Account page with javascript code excution:

```
window.open('/apex/Contratto?X={!Account.Id}',"self");
```

this code, after a user clicks the button , opens the Contratto visualforce page and passes the Account id inside the variable X.
Now in the salesforce classic it works fine but in salesforce1 it doesn't work. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: "Enable Mobile on your VF page and the Button will be available." this comment is present on Bob's post and Mike has given positive confirmation. Will you please try that. Please update if this solves your problem so others to benefit
Ref: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2014/08/replace-visualforce-buttons-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Salesforce1 doesn't accept javascript buttons. There are some workarounds that you can use, however. [This post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.pt/2014/08/replace-visualforce-buttons-in.html) from Bob Buzzard's blog is one of them.